# JSoup match exact text with space in it

Tags: java, regex, jsoup

I'd like to select only an exact String(that has spaces in it) using Jsoup. I'm using matches(^String with spaces$) but the selector is matching with text in the dom that has the world 'String' and not exactly 'String with spaces'.

For example:
Alzheimer's symptom

```html
<a href="/alzheimers-disease/memory-lost-and-found-alzheimers-it-wasnt.aspx">Alzheimer's caregivers should make duplicates of the items</a>
<a href="/alzheimers/the-seven-stages-of-dementia.aspx">Alzheimer's symptom</a>
```

I only want the second piece and not the first. What do I need to do to make that work?

Comment: I'm guessing the `'` in the word `Alzheimer's` is throwing you off. For example if you do this `Elements test = doc.select("a:contains(Alzheimer's symptom)");` the `contains` will break the string after the `'`. So that is really just searching for elements that contain `Alzheimer`, that's why both are selected. If you want the second element based on text, you could just search for `symptom` instead.

Comment: I wouldn't just be able to use symptom because then I would get too many results. I need it to be specific. Thanks for the answer though. I wonder why the ' isn't recognized